# Rotating a block to a location

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to rotate the block so that when the user points to a particular location on the screen, the block rotates to that location and the bullet moves at the angle and collides with another block. So Far I can only get it to point straight. I understand this need basic trig, but when i use this on the bullet, the bullet rotates, going straight, rather than to a location.

```
import pygame
import random

# Define some colors
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)
blue     = (   0,   0, 255)

# --- Classes

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the block. """
    def __init__(self, color):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 15])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the Player. """

    def __init__(self):
        """ Set up the player on creation. """
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(red)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        """ Update the player's position. """
        # Get the current mouse position. This returns the position
        # as a list of two numbers.
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Set the player x position to the mouse x position
        self.rect.x = pos[0] 

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the bullet . """
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
        self.image.fill(black)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        """ Move the bullet. """
        self.rect.y -= 5


# --- Create the window

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

# --- Sprite lists

# This is a list of every sprite. All blocks and the player block as well.
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# List of each block in the game
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# List of each bullet
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# --- Create the sprites

for i in range(50):
    # This represents a block
    block = Block(blue)

    # Set a random location for the block
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(350)

    # Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

# Create a red player block
player = Player()
all_sprites_list.add(player)

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0
player.rect.y = 370

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Event Processing
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Fire a bullet if the user clicks the mouse button
            bullet = Bullet()
            # Set the bullet so it is where the player is
            bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x
            bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
            # Add the bullet to the lists
            all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
            bullet_list.add(bullet)

    # --- Game logic

    # Call the update() method on all the sprites
    all_sprites_list.update()

    # Calculate mechanics for each bullet
    for bullet in bullet_list:

        # See if it hit a block
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)

        # For each block hit, remove the bullet and add to the score
        for block in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 1
            print( score )

        # Remove the bullet if it flies up off the screen
        if bullet.rect.y < -10:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    # --- Draw a frame

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(white)

    # Draw all the spites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 20 frames per second
    clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now, you subtract 5 from a bullets position for it to move up. You need to introduce 2 new variables in the Bullet class. A horizontal and a vertical speed. When a user clicks, you should calculate the 2 speeds, and create a new bullet with these attributes.

As for calculating the speed: you need to use the pythagorean theorem. We know the player position, and the mouse. The difference between those 2 points is their distance. In order to get the horizontal and vertical speed, you need to divide those 2 numbers (the x and y coordinate) So that x*x + y*y = BULLET_SPEED*2.

```
DIVISOR = sqrt((x^2 + y^2) / BULLET_SPEED^2)
```

Then your velocity is:

```
vx = x/DIVISOR
```